# Кеширование ajax запросов (No JQuery)

Tags: php, javascript, кэширование

```
function getXHTTP(){
        var xmlhttp;
        try {
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e) {
            try {
                xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (E) {
                xmlhttp = false;
            }
        }
        if (!xmlhttp && typeof XMLHttpRequest!='undefined') {
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        return xmlhttp;
}
```

есть поле ввода для тегов, снизу есть панель для подсказок, в которую загружаются теги из бд, в зависимости от того, что ввел юзер, подсказки - одним словом... 
нужно кешировать эти подсказки как здесь(https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)

как собственно кешировать  данные ajax запросов?

Comment: Зачем эта функция у вас в вопросе?

Answer (score 2):

Заведите массив. И каждый раз, когда вы догружаете подсказки через ajax - засовывайте их в этот самый массив.